# Where can I get a Job that involves bicycles?

Tags: advocacy, advice

I was wondering if anyone knows any job or if you could advise as of what I could do to obtain a new job that involves bicycles?

Comment: Perhaps... a bike shop?

Comment: Would you please clarify the nature of job that involves bikes? Is it being a bike salesman, repairman/mechanic, bike fit tech, design lighter and stronger bike frames, inventor of new bike gearing system, or the sorts?

Answer (score 2):

The "dirt" magazine (137/july 2013) has a small article on that. Possible jobs listed are:

- working in a bike shop
- pro rider
- writer (in mags, web)
- photographer
- guide (riding instructor)
- industry related (designer, marketing)

So, you'd need to find out which of the above you are best at and start contacting people, sending cvs etc.

Comment: Advocacy, policy, and planning are going to be big areas of real jobs in the coming years!

Comment: Don't forget engineering and manufacturing! R&D is important so if you have an interest in science maybe you'll come up with the next carbon fiber manufacturing process!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the list @cherouvim posted, you could also get a job as a bike messenger if you live in a large enough city and are exceptionally crazy.

Comment: Is that crazy as in insane, or crazy as in "crazy about bikes"?

Comment: From the one person I knew that did it, both.